# Loopback : How can we make query through model object in custom mixins

Tags: node.js, express, mixins, loopback

I am using **Loopback 3.x** .
Created a cusom mixin in **common/mixins** folder and it is working fine.
Now I need to make a query inside **custom-mixin.js**

How can I make a query like `User.find()` inside that?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a query like User.find() inside that?

You can access the model class via `this`.

If your mixin method is static (defined on the model class/constructor):

```
this.find();
```

If your mixin method is defined on the model prototype:

```
this.constructor.find();
```